# Implement multilogin restriction in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, session

**I have one problem when "A" user logged in from 1 PC using "ABC" credentials.similarly when "B" User login from another PC using same credentials the "A" user must be kick out from his account.I have tried it with using session id and IP but it works only on local host .when i upload it on the server it stops working.So please help me and suggest me some way to do it which will be effective on server.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One of the way you can do is to create a GUID ( or use the SessionId ) for every login , when you get to know that B user is logged in then find all the GUIDs (SessionId) related to same userid and Destroy all the Session using by  the GUID . Save either the GUID or SessionId in the database and in the login check if you get the User Id is logged in from the Another machine call a code to remove all the Session with Session Id stored in the database

```
      Table
        User Id , SessionId 
         XXXX      123456789
```

When you validate the login , run a query to see

```
     SELECT * FROM Table where User Id = xxxx
```

Loop through all the records and destroy the Session